# Storing entity relationships as JSON-LD for automated entity extraction

Tags: rdf, json-ld, named-entity-extraction

We're using MITIE (https://github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE) to identify named entities in a text document. The original text document is stored as JSON-LD type textDigitalDocument (http://schema.org/TextDigitalDocument) and then passed to MITIE.

MITIE returns location, person and organisation entities, but also returns entities that are likely to be closely related in some way i.e. personA is related to locationA.

Is it possible to store these relationships between entities back into the source JSON-LD and is there a non-specific relation type that could be used? or are we better off using RDF?

Comment: "or are we better off using RDF?": Which RDF serialization do you mean? (as JSON-LD is a RDF serialization)

Comment: If we couldn't store the relationships in the JSON-LD, we'd contemplated encoding in an RDF format in a JSON separate file. Similar to what has been suggested here: https://github.com/iand/rdf-json